# How to use conditional eval using Knitr in a rnw file

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I want to use a conditional eval for a code block in a rnw file using knitr.

when i run the official example: knitr-examples/011-conditional-eval.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<controller>>=
# this variable controls if a chunk should be evaluated
dothis <- TRUE
@

<<chunk1, eval = dothis>>=
print('say hello world')
@

<<chunk2, eval = !dothis>>=
print('silence is gold')
@

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
Writing to file test.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = controller, test.Rnw:6)
Error in check(options) : invalid value for 'eval' : dothis
Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions -> check
Execution halted
```

What am i doing wrong? I am using Rstudio to run the rnw file

Comment: TRUE is TRUE not "TRUE"

Comment: TRUE does not work either :(

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be running Sweave, not knitr.  Check your global or project options in RStudio to see which one it chooses.

Comment: Tnxs! My global settings where on knitr but I was not aware of the project settings..